# JDBC connection type 4

Tags: java, jdbc

In jdbc type 4 connection "driver" has been registered but connection has some error i.e.

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:@localhost:1521:XE","system","manager");
```

***error: -incompatible types,found:- java.sql.connection, required :Connection***

```
import java.sql.*;
class A
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","manager");
            Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rset=stmt.executeQuery("Select * from emp");
            while(rset.next())
            {                               
            System.out.println(rset.getInt(1)+"\t"+rset.getString(2)+"\t"+rset.getString(3)+"\t"+ rset.getFloat (4));
            }
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you using the right thin jdbc driver for oracle?

Comment: Errors should not be ignored as if they are for decoration only. Errors tell something about the cause of the problem. You know, once a cause is *understood*, a solution is nothing more than obvious. Here, on Stack Overflow, we can translate the error in layman's terms so that you *understand* the cause. So, please edit your question to include the exact error :)

Comment: i have updated the question again .. let see and me answer following is the program

Comment: search a file into oracle i.e. "tnsnames.ora" to send the parameter into getConnection() method. "jdbc:oracle:thin" will come as it is but rest of all need to change according to ur oracle version.code is correct for oracle 10g Database Express Edition. following the following link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this error message is a compiler error message. It means that your code is in the default package, and you have a class in this default package which is named Connection. `DriverManager.getConnection(...)` returns a java.sql.Connection. Use

```
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(...)
```

or rename your own Connection class to something else.

And don't ever use the default package. It leads to all sorts of problems and should be avoided. Always put your classes in a package of yours.

Comment: thnx yaar ur suggestion was correct i have already and my defind connection class when i hv deleted it .. my program executed... thnx body